# Что делает данный код?

Tags: javascript

```
var obj = {
    setClassToElement: function(element, styles) {
        return element.styles = styles;
    },

    createElement: function(type, className) {
        var element = document.create();
        this.setClassToElement(element, styles);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Данный код создает объект `obj` с двумя функциями: *setClassToElement* и *createElement*.

`return element.styles = styles;` присваивает объекту, переданному в параметр *element*, свойство *styles* и возвращает это значение из функции.

Кроме того, содержит ошибку: у объекта *document* нет метода *create*, поэтому при вызове, скорее всего, будет ошибка.

А также не использует параметр *className*, но пытается взять глобальную для этой функции переменную *styles*.

---

Для того, чтобы поправить ошибки, нужно определиться с тем: что именно ожидается от этого кода?

После этого отправиться [в справку](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Найти там, что функция создания элемента называется [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/DOM/document.createElement)

Обратить внимание на то, что данная функция **принимает параметром tag создаваемого элемента**.

Поэтому вызов ее должен быть таким: `document.createElement(type);`

Далее, отметить, что вместо параметра *className*, в вызываемую функцию *this.setClassToElement* - передается неизвестная переменная *styles*, поэтому стоит все-таки заменить их

```
this.setClassToElement(element, className);
```

Далее, функция `createElement` - ничего не возвращается и ничего не делает с созданным элементом - фактически сейчас она бесполезна.

Для придания смысла, можно вернуть созданный элемент после всех настроек.

```
return element;
```

Чтобы увидеть созданный элемент на экране - его надо добавить в DOM, для этого можно воспользоваться [функцией `appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild).

Для использования - надо определиться с элементом **куда** нужно добавить. Для примера можно использовать элемент *body*.

в итоге вызов будет выглядеть так:

```
document.body.appendChild(obj.createElement('h1', 'container'));
```

Теперь стоит обратить внимание на функцию *setClassToElement*, так как она принимает параметром [*HTMLElement*, нужно пойти в справку и посмотреть](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement), что у этого интерфейса нет свойства *styles*, а есть только свойство, *style* - куда можно записать непосредственно правила css. Для присваивания элементу класса можно воспользоваться [свойством *className*](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

```
element.className = styles;
```

Comment: что делает строка return element.styles = styles;?

Comment: @Haski, а у тебя есть какие-нибудь предположения на счет этого?

Comment: ну return -он возвращает значение и потом останавливает ф-цию, только не понятен этот кусок element.styles = styles

Comment: @Grundy, разве есть `styles` у элемента? Вроде `style` только

Comment: @Doofy, этож яваскрипт, если у объекта отсутствует свойство, то при присваивании - оно создастся

Comment: т.е. если записать таким образом `var obj2 = {
 var obj = {
    setClassToElement: function(element, styles) {
        return element.styles = styles;
    },

    createElement: function(type, className) {
        var element = document.createElement();
        this.setClassToElement(element, styles);
    }
    obj.createElement('h1', 'container');
};` данный код будет запускаться без ошибок?

Comment: @Haski, во-первых, достаточно записать таким образом и проверить, во-вторых, запускаться без ошибок будет и код приведенный в вопросе. Ошибки пойдут при вызове конкретных функций. И, опять же, нет - вариант из комментария тоже содержит ошибки.

Comment: как можно это исправить, нужно добавить еще метод appendChild? что бы он появился в html?

Comment: @Haski, _appendChild_ куда?

Comment: в метод createElement

Comment: @Haski, обновил ответ

Comment: Спасибо) сейчас буду разбираться)

Answer (score 0):

Объявляется переменная obj которая содержит два метода: setClassToElement и createElement, описанные в объявлении.

После этого кода можно написать:

```
obj.createElement("button", "my-button");
```

Можно предположить, что с помощью DOM в этих методах устанавливаются класс для элемента и создается элемент соответственно.

А вообще, код, указанный в вопросе, довольно абстрактен. Конкретных вещей каких-то он вроде не делает.

Comment: Можно ли назвать объект переменной в данном случае?

Comment: Ну, пусть будет объект.